# Retrieve rows with 0 count from Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am woking on a query which can give back the count divided by month about the offices that will be closed this summer.

```
SELECT
    qa.tmonth,
    COUNT(qa.tmonth) AS qtn
FROM
(
    SELECT TO_CHAR(CLOSURE_DATE, 'yyyymm') AS tmonth
    FROM Holidays
    WHERE CLOSURE_DATE >= TO_DATE('20160501', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
          CLOSURE_DATE <= TO_DATE('20160901', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
) qa
GROUP BY qa.tmonth;
```

Since the months: May, June, August and September no office will be closed the output is the following:

```
TMONTH|QTN
201607|80
```

But I need a thing like this

```
TMONTH|QTN
201605|0
201606|0
201607|80
201608|0
201609|0
```

How could I achieve that?

Thanks to all!

Comment: If no office closes in a given summer month, then there are no records to aggregate into a count.  In this case, you would probably need to join to a calendar table to fill in the missing months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
SQL> with holidays(closure_date) as
  2  (
  3    select date '2016-07-01' from dual union all
  4    select date '2016-07-02' from dual union all
  5    select date '2016-07-03' from dual union all
  6    select date '2016-07-04' from dual union all
  7    select date '2016-07-05' from dual
  8  )
  9  select count(closure_date) as closure_days, to_char(day, 'yyyymm') as month
 10  from (
 11          select date '2016-05-01' + level -1 as day
 12          from dual
 13          connect by date '2016-05-01' + level -1 <= date '2016-09-30'
 14       ) days
 15       left outer join holidays
 16         on (day = closure_date)
 17  group by to_char(day, 'yyyymm') ;

CLOSURE_DAYS MONTH
------------ ------
           0 201608
           5 201607
           0 201606
           0 201605
           0 201609

SQL>
```

This uses a query to build the list of all the days between a starting and an ending date; I used 01/05 and 30/09 and called it `days`.

Then it queries `days` with the `holidays` table in outer join; this way you can count only the days for which there is a corrensponding value in the closure days list, thus counting the closure days for each day, month year; the aggregation for year and month completes the job

Comment: I tried it but it gives all months with 0 count even on July where there were 80 rows

Comment: Just edited to show how it works with some sample data; please post an extract of your starting data to show the problem

Comment: I was forgetting to format the string since I dont need the time I modified it a little and works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach like above. Tip: You can execute the two sub-queries separately, to analyse the logic.

```
select to_char (m.month, 'yyyymm') as TMONTH, m.month, 
       nvl (h.qtn, 0) as QTN
from 
(
  SELECT add_months(trunc (SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), -(LEVEL-1)) as MONTH 
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 -- generate a list of the last 12 month
) m
left join 
(
  SELECT trunc (closure_date, 'MONTH') as MONTH,
         count (*) as QTN
    FROM Holidays
    group by trunc (closure_date, 'MONTH')
) h
on m.MONTH = h.MONTH
where m.month between DATE '2016-01-01' and sysdate
order by TMONTH desc;
```